# Cards will not populate with movie names from TMDB API

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app for a project where you can swipe through movie names and images, for now I am just trying to get the names working but my cards will not populate with the movie names. I had some trouble with the array adapter but I think it's working now and in the correct place. I am using a library from github for the cards and it's worked for other programs just can't get it work with this. Maybe it's because of the model class? just lost when there is no real errors. Item.xml is the design of the card with it's text and background and activity_main.xml is where I reference the library. hellotext is the textview in item.xml. Any help is appreicated!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> al;
    private ArrayAdapter<MovieModelClass> arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<MovieModelClass> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int i;
    String moviename;


    private static String JSON_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8099f5720bad1f61f020fdbc855f73db";
    //List<MovieModelClass> movieList;
    //@InjectView(R.id.frame) SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetData getData = new GetData();
        getData.execute();

      


        //AddArray();

        // ButterKnife.inject(this);

        //this add is the name of the card, with each add another card is added
        //adds into array
        //the array has a text and a layout we create
        //this layout is the card in itself textview picture ect...



        //this is when it actually swipes(clicks and movies)
        SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {

            //every time a card is completely removed he just removes it from the array
            //notifies the adapter of this change
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                movieList.remove(0);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                //Do something on the left!
                //You also have access to the original object.
                //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
                // Ask for more data here
               // movieList.add();
             //   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             //   Log.d("LIST", "notified");
              //  i++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
               /* View view = flingContainer.getSelectedView();
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_right_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent < 0 ? -scrollProgressPercent : 0);
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_left_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent > 0 ? scrollProgressPercent : 0);*/
            }


        });


        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Api (same class)

```
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String current = "";

            try {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                try {

                    url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                    int data = isr.read();
                    while (data != -1) {
                        current += (char) data;
                        data = isr.read();
                    }

                    return current;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        //  urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return current;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull String s){

            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();
                  //  model.setId(jsonObject1.getString("vote_average"));
                    model.setName(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                  //  model.setImg(jsonObject1.getString("poster_path"));


                    moviename = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                    model.setName(moviename);



                    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
                    movieList.add(model);

  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, movieList);


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Update***

I fixed the null problem BUT my cards now populate with my project name so I just see one card with  com.project300.populateswipecards... any help?

```
    private ArrayList<String> al;
    private ArrayAdapter<MovieModelClass> arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<MovieModelClass> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int i;
    String moviename = "";
    Context context;

    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;



    private static String JSON_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8099f5720bad1f61f020fdbc855f73db";
    //List<MovieModelClass> movieList;
    //@InjectView(R.id.frame) SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);



        GetData getData = new GetData();
        getData.execute();




        //AddArray();

        // ButterKnife.inject(this);

        //this add is the name of the card, with each add another card is added
        //adds into array
        //the array has a text and a layout we create
        //this layout is the card in itself textview picture ect...



        //this is when it actually swipes(clicks and movies)


        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {


            //every time a card is completely removed he just removes it from the array
            //notifies the adapter of this change
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
              //  Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
              //  movieList.remove(0);
              //  arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                //Do something on the left!
                //You also have access to the original object.
                //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
                // Ask for more data here
               // movieList.add();
             //   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             //   Log.d("LIST", "notified");
              //  i++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
               /* View view = flingContainer.getSelectedView();
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_right_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent < 0 ? -scrollProgressPercent : 0);
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_left_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent > 0 ? scrollProgressPercent : 0);*/
            }


        });


        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String current = "";

            try {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                try {

                    url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                    int data = isr.read();
                    while (data != -1) {
                        current += (char) data;
                        data = isr.read();
                    }

                    return current;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        //  urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return current;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull String s){



            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();

                    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
                    //  model.setId(jsonObject1.getString("vote_average"));
                    //   model.setName(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                    //  model.setImg(jsonObject1.getString("poster_path"));


                    moviename = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                    model.setName(moviename);
                    movieList.add(model);


                    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, movieList);

                    flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your `onPostExecute()` method, I see this:

> ```
> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, movieList);
> ```

I think you're assuming that this will update the list of cards, since earlier in `onCreate()` you have written this:

> ```
> flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
> ```

However, that is not how the `new` keyword and Java object references work. These two adapters are completely separate, and `flingContainer` doesn't "see" the adapter you create in your task.

The easiest way to solve this is likely to re-set the adapter after you create it.

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, movieList);
flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

---

Now the problem seems to be this `for` loop:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
>     // ...
>
>     movieList = new ArrayList<>();
>     // ...
>     movieList.add(model);    
>
>     arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, movieList);
>     flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
>     arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
> }
> ```

You need to move the `ArrayList` creation and adapter logic outside of the loop.

```
movieList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    // ...
    movieList.add(model);  
}

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, movieList);
flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense I should have noticed that earlier. I did that but unfortunately it throws an exception because my arrayadpater is null now but my movieList is populated with the movie name? how come the adapter wont populate

Comment: Please update your question with the new code and the stack trace, and I'll take a look.

Comment: I fixed the null error but the adapter is still coming up null

Comment: Thank you! This has given me multiple cards but it still only shows my project name "com.project300.populateswipecards", should I have created an extra adapter class or will it work with just the simple adapter I declared?

Comment: Ah. The problem there is that you're using a generic `ArrayAdapter`. Your model classes are not `String`s, so it's just calling `.toString()` on them I suspect. You'll need to override the `getView()` method; should be plenty of tutorials on how to do that on this site / the general internet.

Comment: Alternatively, for now, you could switch your `movieList` to be `ArrayList<String>` and just add the title of the movie to the list. That should let you see the names.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the changing to a string worked. I will look into overriding the get view method I created a simple adapter but it isn't working for me at the moment.